# node-simplecrawler: ajaxed content pages crawl issue

Tags: ajax, node.js, web-crawler

I'm using [this script](https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler) for crawling some shopping sites. I have a huge issue that make this script and any other worthless for me.

We are planing to crawl a page a shopping website called digikala (www.digikala.com). The problem is the main product grids load their data from an AJAX call.

for example this page : http://www.digikala.com/Search/Category-Mobile-Phone/#!/Brand-10/Category-Electronic-Devices/Category-Mobile/Category-Mobile-Phone/

If you see your firebug/developer-console you will see that the products grid of this category is loading after an AJAX post call. So how can I crawl this product pages?

Add some wait (for example 10 sec) before fetch the page will fix the issue?

Comment: repo issue link : https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler/issues/159

Answer (score 0):

option1: use browser simulation , suck as phantomjs,

option2: checkout the ajax url from developer tool, get data directly from the url. be careful, may need special header, or some kind of validation.